# How to draw Diamond And zick zack shape in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to draw a diamond in zick-zack as like circle. please anybody help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have a draw Diamond Thish code use to draw Diamond

int mgX = penThickness * 6;
  int mgY = penThickness * 2;

```
    CGPoint st = CGPointMake(MIN(startingPt.x, endingPt.x), MIN(startingPt.y, endingPt.y));
    CGPoint et = CGPointMake(MAX(startingPt.x, endingPt.x), MAX(startingPt.y, endingPt.y));

    CGRect outsideRect = CGRectMake(st.x,st.y, MAX(mgX, et.x-st.x), MAX(mgY, et.y-st.y));
    CGRect insideRect  = CGRectInset(outsideRect, outsideRect.size.width * 0.30f, outsideRect.size.height * 0.30f);

    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(insideRect), CGRectGetMinY(outsideRect));

    //0 line
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(insideRect), CGRectGetMinY(outsideRect));


    //1 line
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(outsideRect), CGRectGetMidY(insideRect));

    //2 line
     CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(insideRect), CGRectGetMaxY(outsideRect));


    //3 line
     CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(insideRect), CGRectGetMaxY(outsideRect));

    //4 line

    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(outsideRect), CGRectGetMidY(insideRect));

    CGPathCloseSubpath(pathRef);
```

Answer (score 4):

i have complet Draw Complet in Hexagone thish code working in draw Haxagon

int mgX = penThickness * 6; 
int mgY = penThickness * 6;

```
CGPoint st = CGPointMake(MIN(startingPt.x, endingPt.x), MIN(startingPt.y, endingPt.y));
CGPoint et = CGPointMake(MAX(startingPt.x, endingPt.x), MAX(startingPt.y, endingPt.y));

CGRect outsideRect = CGRectMake(st.x,st.y, MAX(mgX, et.x-st.x), MAX(mgY, et.y-st.y));
CGRect insideRect  = CGRectInset(outsideRect, outsideRect.size.width * 0.30f, outsideRect.size.height * 0.30f);

CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(insideRect), CGRectGetMinY(outsideRect));

//0 line
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(insideRect), CGRectGetMinY(outsideRect));


//1 line
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(outsideRect), CGRectGetMidY(insideRect));

//2 line
 CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(insideRect), CGRectGetMaxY(outsideRect));


//3 line
 CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(insideRect), CGRectGetMaxY(outsideRect));

//4 line

CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(outsideRect), CGRectGetMidY(insideRect));

CGPathCloseSubpath(pathRef);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to draw shapes in iOS.

**Using**

- [CGContextRef](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_5_iPhone_Graphics_Drawing_Tutorial_using_Quartz_2D)
- [BezierPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html)